# Glowworm swarm optimization (GSO) algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, gso

Is there any open source library with some sort of Glowworm swarm optimization (GSO) algorithm implementation? I would like to implement it based on description http://www.springerlink.com/content/y065470472612847. Any suggestions?

Comment: When I was creating that questions there wasn't tag GSO and I am not permitted to create new ones (I used PSO ...).

Answer (score 1):

Page 91 of the linked paper contains a pretty concise pseudocode description of the algorithm.

Comment: I publicated some dirty implementation at http://ngso.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets . I would be grateful for finding mistakes

Comment: It looks like your implementation iterates through every agent for each iteration when searching for neighbors.  If the search space is dimension 2 or greater, with a reasonable number of agents (hundreds or more) you could get a good speedup by using a spatial index, like an R-Tree to do the neighbor searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a C++ implementation here: https://bitbucket.org/irrati0nal/glowworm

Hope it helps.

Unfortunately, it does not work on Mac OS. And there are a lots of problem with the header function :(

Comment: thanks I created some code (c#) at http://ngso.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15860